# Android web market always gives error

Tags: google-play-store, installation, web-market

I am getting error for almost all the apps while I am trying to install from web android market (market.android.com), it gives error "This item cannot be installed in your device's country.". But same time If I tries to install same application from my mobile then it installs successfully. So does anybody have any idea why it's giving this error ? (Note : I had installed new market and then uninstalled it. This problem starts after installation of new market only).

Mobile model : Samsung Galaxy 3

Country : India

Comment: You could try Market Enabler to fake being in the US and see if that helps, though it doesn't explain why this happens.

Comment: Can you check if there are more than one device registered in your market account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the device location is detected from the SIM card in use.

I'm not sure how the web market location is detected. Perhaps look at using a proxy.

But if you wish your change your SIM location check this out:
https://market.android.com/details?id=ch.racic.android.marketenabler

Answer (score 0):

Such sites have geographic filters so you may need to access those sites in mobile which passes the [IP barrier](http://www.accitron.com).

Comment: Please don't add promotional links without disclosing your relationship to the company.

Comment: It is required per FAQ of this site that you have to disclose your affiliation with the mentioned service. Please edit your answer to fulfil this requirement.